# Setting the language level to java 8 makes some methods disappear

Tags: java, maven, java-8

I'm currently trying to setup a `Beam` interactive app using its API but I'm running into a problem.

```
    BeamAPI beam = new BeamAPI("oauthtoken");
    BeamUser user = beam.use(UsersService.class).getCurrent().get();

        pro.beam.interactive.robot.Robot robot = new RobotBuilder()
                .channel(user.channel)
                .build(beam, false)
                .get();

        robot.on(Protocol.Report.class, report -> {
            // If we have any joysticks in the report

            if (report.getJoystickCount() > 0) {
                // Get the coordMean from the joystick
                Protocol.Coordinate coordMean = report.getJoystick(0).getCoordMean();
                Point mousePosition = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();

                // Apply it to the current mouse position, if its values are not NaN
                if (!Double.isNaN(coordMean.getX()) && !Double.isNaN(coordMean.getY())) {
                }
            }
        });


}
```

The problem is that methods such as the `getJoystickCount` aren't showing up and aren't being resolved, however if I set my language level to java 7 all the methods show up correctly but the code doesn't work since it uses lambdas from Java 8.

All the maven settings are set for java 8 as well as project settings and decompiling the `Protocol` class all the methods are right in there.

What could be causing this problem?

This is my POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>beamplays</groupId>
<artifactId>splix</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>beam-releases</id>
        <url>https://maven.beam.pro/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>beam-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://maven.beam.pro/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pro.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pro.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>interactive</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Show Us your maven pom file, also which IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using IntellIJ Idea, I added the pom file to the question

Comment: Add `<version>3.6.1</version>` in the maven compiler plugin dependency, clean your project and update it (don't know where it is in IntellIJ, in eclipse it would be alt+f5) then check it again

Comment: @JorgeCampos. Not really moving the discussion forward here, but in my browser's default font, "m" looks a lot like "r+n". I was a little taken aback by the phrase "pom file" :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist lol hard now :) !! I will write it in upper case next time! Thanks for the heads up!!

Comment: @JorgeCampos That didn't work, still the same

Comment: So, I tried running the code even with that error and I got this stacktrace:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/Message

Comment: That was the problem

Comment: Yeah it means that you didn't added all required dependencies on your POM file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running the code even with the error and got a NoClassDefFoundError askin for Google Protobuf, after adding it everything worked fine.